# Correlation of two random variables as functions

Tags: probability, correlation, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, covariance

> Consider 2 random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$:
>
> - $X_1 = Y_1 \sqrt{\alpha + \beta {X_0}^2}$
> - $X_2 = Y_2 \sqrt{\alpha + \beta {X_1}^2}$
>
> $ \alpha>0 $ , $\beta \ge 0$
>
> where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent and both follow a normal standard distribution $N (0, 1)$. Also, $Y_1$ is independent of $X_0$ and $Y_2$ is independent of $X_1$.
>
> Find the correlation between $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Based off these informations, I know that $X_1 | X_0 = x_0$ ∼ $N(0, \alpha + \beta x_0^2)$ and  $X_2 | X_1 = x_1$ ∼ $N(0, \alpha + \beta x_1^2)$. Also, the equation for $X_2$ tells me that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are positively correlated. I thought of applying this formula:

- $Cov(X_1,X_2) = E[Cov(X_1,X_2|Z)] + Cov[E(X_1|Z),E(X_2|Z)]$

but I tried using $Z=X_0$ and $Z=X_1$ it seems like it doesn't work. Am I choosing the wrong formula?